# If "min_index_age" is determined using the index creation time as reference what is the significance of @timestamp field in the datastream[Opensearch]

Tags: opensearch

I am currently migrating some timeseries data stored in a regular index to a datastream managed using ISM policies. The policy definition is provided below

```
{
    "policy": {
        "policy_id": "policy1",
        "description": "policy for ingesting sensor data",
        "default_state": "hot",
        "states": [{
                "name": "hot",
                "actions": [{
                    "rollover": {
                        "min_size": "32gb"
                    }
                }],
                "transitions": [{
                    "state_name": "delete",
                    "conditions": {
                        "min_index_age": "30d"
                    }
                }]
            },
            {
                "name": "delete",
                "actions": [{
                    "delete": {}
                }],
                "transitions": []
            }
        ],
        "ism_template": [{
            "index_patterns": [
                "sensordata_*_history*"
            ],
            "priority": 100
        }]
    }
}
```

I would have assumed that the deletion would happen based on the @timestamp field, i.e. if an index contains all data that is older than 30d, then the index would be deleted.

But it seems the index creation time is used as the reference time, then what is the purpose of the @timestamp field in the datastream ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, ISM policy will trigger the time based action with reference to index creation time.

`@timestamp` filed is most likely to use by the Kibana to plot the time based histogram.